# Choosing column to search by in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, rest

I am writing a Django REST Framework-based app and I want to choose the field to search with in the API

DB model definition:

```py
class Log(models.Model):
    """Define staging Log format"""
    fkhistory = models.ForeignKey(History, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    log = models.TextField()
    logdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Serializer:

```py
class LogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Defines log table"""
    fkhistory = FkHistorySerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
    sequence = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    log = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

I am able to query the table with `/api/log/<id>` but I would like to query it with `/api/log/<fkhistory>`

Anyway to do it without reinventing the wheel?
I have tried reading the documentaiton but I found no answers.

Thanks

EDIT: here's the view

```py
class LogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Log.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LogSerializer
```

Comment: Can you post your view ?

Comment: Added to main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view needs to include `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` to achieve the desired result.

```
class LogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  lookup_field = 'fkhistory'
  lookup_url_kwarg = 'fkhistory'
  queryset = Log.objects.all()
  serializer_class = LogSerializer
```

The url should read as `/api/log/<int:fkhistory>/`

Also if you like you can modify your serializer as:

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Defines log table"""
  class Meta(object):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = '__all__'
```

Note: The view will give `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception if multiple objects exist for the given `fkhistory`. To avoid that I suggest you use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey` if your requirement allows.

Refer to [DRF Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) and [Classy DRF](http://www.cdrf.co/) for more details.